# How to interpret "se trouver" in the expression "s'en est trouvé facilité"?

Tags: sens

> Le premier scan en l'an 2000 a changé notre vie à tous! Le diagnostic **s'en est trouvé facilité, accéléré**; pur bonheur de pouvoir rassurer un patient inquiet quand le résultat est normal ou bénin; soulagement de pouvoir traiter rapidement quand on trouve un problème.

I'm not sure of the meaning of the reflexive "se trouver" here. It does not seem to denote *coïncidence* or *se sentir* which I usually associate "se trouver" with.

I wonder if it is close in meaning to "se retrouver" in the sense of *finir* in this specific instance?

Comment: Well you can translate it as "the diagnostic found itself to be eased" or "the diagnostic was found to be eased" and the "en" meaning that it was eased by "it" where it stands for the scan. So the meaning is that the diagnostic became eased, accelerated.

Comment: @dannemp In a nutshell, yes. And I have no problem understanding that basic meaning of the phrase in English. What I hope to figure out here is the precise meaning of "se trouver" which does not seem to fit any of the common uses of the phrase that I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While without *en*, ***se trouver*** can mean something happens fortuitously, with *en*, ***s'en est trouvé*** introduces a change or a new status which is a consequence of what *en* is referring to.

e.g.

> - Oui, monsieur, répondit d'Artagnan en s'inclinant, nous avons eu cet honneur ; nous avons même, comme vous avez pu l'entendre, introduit sous un des angles un baril de poudre qui, en éclatant, a fait une fort jolie brèche ; sans compter que, comme le bastion n'était pas d'hier, tout le reste de la bâtisse **s'en est trouvé** fort ébranlé.

Les Trois Mousquetaires, *Alexandre Dumas*

The whole building ended up being destabilized because of the blast.

In your sentence: diagnosis were eased and accelerated because of the availability of scans.

Comment: Alors comme ca, « se trouver » signifie effectivement « finir par », c'est ça ? Intéressant. :) De là à supposer qu'on peut tout aussi bien dire « s'en est **re**trouvé facilité », il n’y a qu’un pas. Cela dit, avec « se retrouver », ce serait comme si la facilité ne provenait que d'un pur hasard.

Comment: « Se trouve » (~ is being) et « s'en être trouvé » ( ~ end up ) ne signifient pas la même chose.  « S'en est retrouvé » est beaucoup plus rare et utilisé différement.

Comment: Hi. http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/trouver/79064#79066 Do you think the 3rd definition fits the bill here? [dans une situation] Even if the examples there only deal with "se trouver + preposition", not "se trouver + adjective / past participle"...

Comment: Not sure "find oneself" can apply to something, not a person. (find itself?)

Comment: Yes, "find oneself" in English is often reserved for  a person, even if there is strictly nothing wrong with applying it to an object, too. But actually, I'm not interested in how to translate the phrase into English, but rather I want to capture the feel of this phrase, just as any native French speaker would do. Do you find the 3rd [dans une situation] definition reasonable enough? If so, "se trouver" in this specific sense seems quite close in meaning to "se retrouver" in the sense of "finir par".

Comment: I cannot make sense of *dans une situation* which is not a verb. Again, don't try to match *se trouver* et *s'en être trouvé*. They are slightly different phrases. The underlying meaning of the sentence is *Les diagnostics étaient complexes et lents.L'arrivée des "scans" a changé cet état de fait en les rendant simples et rapides*.

Comment: Oh, I meant "ça s'est trouvé comme ça" or something like that. Interestingly enough, not any dictionary seems to cover this specific use of "s'en est trouvé". Incidentally, "as it turned out" might best capture the meaning of "s'en est trouvé".

Comment: Yes, *s'en est trouvé* implies either an unexpected consequence or a consequence of an higher level than expected.